# Error in logstash while passing if statement

Tags: logstash

I am new to logstash.When I am trying to put a if statement in logstash config file it gives me error

if statement used is:

```
if {await} > 10 
{ mutate {add_field => {"RULE_DATA" => "Value is above threshold"}
    add_field => {"ACTUAL_DATA" => "%{await}"}
    }
}
```

the error faced is given below:

> [ERROR] 2018-07-20 16:52:21.327 [Ruby-0-Thread-1: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:22] agent - Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, => at line 18, column 10 (byte 729) after filter{\n        grok {\n                patterns_dir => [\"./patterns\"]\n                match => { \"message\" =>  [\"%{TIME:time}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:device}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:tps}%{SPACE}%{SYSLOGPROG:rd_sec/s}%{SPACE}%{SYSLOGPROG:wr_sec/s}%{SPACE}%{SYSLOGPROG:avgrq-sz}%{SPACE}%{SYSLOGPROG:avgqu-sz}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:await}%{SPACE}%{SYSLOGPROG:svctm}%{SPACE}%{SYSLOGPROG:%util}\"]\n                        }\n                overwrite => [\"message\"]\n        }                \n        if \"_grokparsefailure\" in [tags] {\n                drop { }\n        }\nif {await", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:42:in `compile_imperative'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:50:in`compile_graph'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:12:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2486:in`map'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `compile_sources'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:51:in`initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:169:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:in`execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:315:in `block in converge_state'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in`with_pipelines'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:312:in `block in converge_state'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in`each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:299:in `converge_state'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:166:in`block in converge_state_and_update'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in `with_pipelines'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:164:in`converge_state_and_update'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:90:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:348:in`block in execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in `block in initialize'"]}

Please suggest what has caused this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error. If you have a field as name it await. Like output of grok parse etc.
use the below

```
if [await] > 10 
{ 
    mutate {
       add_field => {"RULE_DATA" => "Value is above threshold"}
       add_field => {"ACTUAL_DATA" => "%{await}"}
    }
}
```

Comment: If this answer solves your question feel free to accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Logstash conditional's expression enclosed in `[]` not `{}`, have a look at the following example from [conditional documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals),

```
filter {
  if [action] == "login" {
    mutate { remove_field => "secret" }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, but when i was closing it in square bracket it was giving error "comparing string with 10", so i changed to curly braces, doing this resolved that error. Not sure if this was correct.

Comment: whats in `action` field ? can you post actual log